# ionic IBM MobileFirst platform 8.0 sqladapter ReferenceError: WL is not defined

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

this is my service.js,using Wl.Client.invoke,dont know which files i am missing ,do i need wlinit.js or initoptions.js or do i need to install any plugin

```
    .factory('loginservice', function(){
    var user;
    return{
           checkvalue:function(settings){
                    user=settings;
                    console.log(user);
                    var invocationData = {
                            adapter : 'sqltest2',
                            procedure : 'checkvalue',
                            parameters : [user.username,user.password]
                                            };
                    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
                        onSuccess : loginSuccess,
                        onFailure : loginFailure
                                                             });

                    function loginSuccess(result){
                        console.log("Retrieve success" +  JSON.stringify(result));
                        //displayFeeds(result.invocationResult.resultSet);
                                                }

                    function loginFailure(result){  
                        console.log("Retrieve failure");
                                                    }

                }                   

                }
              })
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Have you installed the mfp cordova plugin? Are you facing issues running the application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IBM MobileFirst platform 8.0** sqladapter ReferenceError: **WL is not defined**

I assume you are using IBM MobileFirst platform 8.0,  You have to install **mfpdev-cli** & **cordova-plugin-mfp** then use **WLResourceRequest**. see the sample:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    "/adapters/JavaAdapter/users",
    WLResourceRequest.GET
);
var formParams = {"param1": "value1", "param2": "value2"};
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParams);

resourceRequest.send().then(
    onSuccess,
    onFailure
)
```

**WL.Client.invokeProcedure** is no longer in use in IBM MobileFirst 8.0.

I suggest that you will take a tour of the MobileFirst Foundation development in Cordova applications  . See here:

Integrating MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 in Ionic-based apps: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/19/integrating-mobilefirst-foundation-8-in-ionic-based-apps/

Adding the MobileFirst Foundation SDK to Cordova Applications: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/

Resource request from JavaScript (Cordova, Web) applications: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/javascript/